# Ansible Recursive Directory Copy

Tags: ansible

Ansible version: 2.2.1.0

I'm having trouble copying the contents of a directory to a destination host in Ansible. My role directory structure looks like this:

```
roles/server/
├── defaults
│   └── main.yml
├── files
│   ├── Common-x86_64.repo
│   ├── docker-ce-stable.repo
|
├── handlers
│   └── main.yml
├── meta
│   └── main.yml
├── README.md
├── tasks
│   ├── main.yml
│   └── packages.yml
├── templates
├── tests
│   ├── inventory
│   └── test.yml
└── vars
    └── main.yml
```

There are a lot (about 12 more) repos in the files directory, I've omitted most for the sake of keeping it short. I'm running this code in `packages.yml`

```
- name: 1. Setup Repos
     file:
       src: files/
       dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/
       owner: root
       group: root
       mode: 0644
```

Even though the task is completing without error, nothing is copying into `/etc/yum.repos.d/` on the target machine:

```
ls /etc/yum.repos.d/
CentOS-Base.repo       CentOS-Media.repo    CentOS-fasttrack.repo
CentOS-CR.repo         CentOS-Sources.repo
CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  CentOS-Vault.repo
```

I read on the documentation page that ending a source directory with a `/` causes the contents to be copied recursively. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`file` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/file_module.html) is **not** for copying the files, but for setting attributes of files on the target.

[`copy` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/copy_module.html) is for copying.

Comment: How embarrassing, I knew that, and I was meaning to use the `copy` module all along. I even had the documentation open, but typed `file` in the code instead. I didn't realize I had typed file until I read your answer. Then I got so fixated on source and destination. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Providing some additional information to the accepted answer..

Recursive copy using directory paths has the following disadvantages:

- you cannot get changed state information per file copied
- so `--check` and `--check --diff` flags won't show anything
- you cannot include/exclude specific files/directories to/from the recursion
- performing corrective changes after the bulk copy will never produce a state with `changed=0` and could also affect files that already existed on remote host.

There seems to be a more powerful  way to perform a recursive copy, which is to use `with_filetree` combined with `when`

```
- name: "create-remote-dirs"
  file:
    path: /dest/dir/{{item.path}}
    state: directory
    mode:  '0775'
  with_filetree: sourceDir/
  when: item.state == 'directory'
- name: "copy-files"
  copy:
    src: "{{item.src}}"
    dest: /dest/dir/{{item.path}}
    mode:  '0744'
  with_filetree: sourceDir/
  # combinations of 'is' and 'is not' can be used below.
  when: item.state == 'file' 
        and item.path is not search("excludedDir/*")
        and item.path is not search("*.bak")
```

Answer (score 4):

Source files and directories can be stored inside `files` directory. If you put them in other folders it may not get found.

***Copy file:***

```
copy:
  src: src_filename 
  dest: to_be_parent/src_filename
```

results into `to_be_parent/src_filename`. Destination filename may or may not be equal to src filename.

***Copy directory:***

```
copy:
  src: mydirectory
  dest: to_be_parent
```

results into `to_be_parent/mydirectory`

```
copy:
  src: mydirectory/
  dest: to_be_parent
```

results into `to_be_parent/contents_of_mydirectory`

**Not so desired result in below case:**

```
copy:
  src: mydirectory
  dest: to_be_parent/mydirectory
```

results into `to_be_parent/mydirectory/mydirectory/contents_of_mydirectory`